# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning on basic np.where statement

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting this error `SettingWithCopyWarning` on this command. The command works fine, but returns this error. Is there an alternative way of doing while not receiving the error?

```
 # Grab DataFrame rows where column has certain values and create 'signature' string
    test['signature'] = np.where(test['id'].isin(list_of_bad_ids), 'id has a bad value in it', test['signature'])


See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  test['signature'] = np.where(test['id'].isin(list_of_bad_ids), 'id has a bad value in it', test['signature'])
<command-1510344588518966>:43: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably not due to the `np.where` function call, but related to your assignment to `test['signature']`.

If your code looks like this:

```py
df = pd.read_...
test = df.loc[...]

test['signature'] = np.where(
    test['id'].isin(list_of_bad_ids), 'id has a bad value in it', test['signature']
)
```

pandas is actually warning you that it understands test is a view of `df`, but it is making a copy of it somewhere and then attempting to assign your output of `np.where` to that copy.

The reason this results in a warning is because `pandas` isn't certain if you're expecting this change to propagate back to the original `df` as it would if you were assigning to a view:

```py
df.loc[...] = ...
```

---

If you don't want this output to propagate back to `df` and instead want your `test` DataFrame to be its own entity separate from `df`, you can create `test` as an explicit copy of `df`

```py
df = pd.read_...

# We're explicitly telling pandas that test is NOT a view into `df`
test = df.loc[...].copy() 

test['signature'] = np.where(
    test['id'].isin(list_of_bad_ids), 'id has a bad value in it', test['signature']
)
```

If you do want this result to propagate back to `df`, you can keep your masking operation separate from the data and simply perform a slice & assignment when desired:

```py
df = pd.read_...
row_mask = df['column'] > 0.5
test = df.loc[row_mask]

df.loc[row_mask, 'signature'] = np.where(
    test['id'].isin(list_of_bad_ids), 'id has a bad value in it', test['signature']
)
```